# How to import packages and libraries in android app

Tags: android

few months back i developed an application for jelly bean 4.1.2. Now i need to make my app upward compatible. Now i updated my Android SDK. Please help me to import the packages and libraries in my application.

Comment: Its the same thing, you don't need any change (except manifest if you limited api version it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update ADT plug-in of eclipse and change target sdk version to 19.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

You can update the adt from here

You might need to update the software source for your adt update

Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.

It should list the latest update of adt. If it is not working try this

go to eclipse > help > Install new software

Click on add

add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

give it any name.

It will list the updates available- which should ideally be adt 20.xx

Eclipse will restart and hopefully everything should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

> steps

1. Copy the library file into libs folder select jar file -> right
2. click -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path clean the project Project->
3. Clean -> select your project -> ok

And

From Eclipse, go to Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager. Then, in Available Packages, select the SDK versions you want to install. (note that you might also want to select Android SDK Tools) When the installation is finished, you should also update the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

To use a certain SDK release for you project, go to project properties (right click on the project and select Properties) and select (from the Android page) the desired Project Build Target.